# Erro de function quando utilizada em outra pagina

Tags: php, funções, variáveis

Tenho o seguinda código

```
class Auth {
    function getMemberByUsername($username) {
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "Select * from members where member_name = ?";
        $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query, 's', array($username));
        return $result;
    }
}
```

na index chamo `$user = $auth->getMemberByUsername($username);` e consigo utilizar a variavel user normalmente. Na mesma classe tenho também a seguinte fuction:

```
function getMemberNivel($level) {
    $db_handle = new DBController();
    $query = "Select * from members where nivel = ?";
    $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query, 'i', array($level));
    return $result;
}
```

e chamo da seguinte forma:

```
$phase = $auth->getMemberNivel($level);
```

porém me informa que a variavel `$level` nao existe, nao entendo o que ocorre, se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço, pois ja perdi horas quebrando a cabeça com algo que talvez seja muito simples.

Comment: Nossa, tava tudo organizado, na hora de publicar bagunçou tudo

Comment: O SO usa markdown, no campo de texto da pergunta tem uma explicação de como usar o principal. E da onde saiu essa variável `$level`?

Comment: Estou meio que iniciante ainda, nao entendi, o que vc quer dizer com SO e markdown?? e a variavel $level está ali declarada dentro da função, assim como a $username.

Comment: Estou pesquisando markdown

Comment: SO = StackOverflow (site de perguntas e respostas que estamos usando). Markdown = linguagem de marcação (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Qual a linha em que surge o erro?

Comment: NESTA: $phase = $auth->getMemberNivel($level); ele nao reconhece a variavel level, mas ela esta ali na função.... não é assim ? segui o exemplo das demais, pois no mesmo arquivo tem diverrsas outras funções, apenas copiei a funçao getMemberByUsername e alterei o nome da variavel e o select

Comment: Seu erro é de lógica de programação, quando tu chama uma função passando argumentos, esses devem existir, por exemplo, `$level = 5; $phase = $auth->getMemberNivel($level);` se não declarar a variável antes de passar como argumento de uma função dará erro, pois está passando algo que não existe (não foi declarado)

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer a seguinte alteração em ambas as funções.

```
function getMemberByUsername($username='') {
   $db_handle = new DBController();
   $query = "Select * from members where member_name = ?";
   $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query, 's', array($username));
   return $result;
}

function getMemberNivel($level='') {
   $db_handle = new DBController();
   $query = "Select * from members where nivel = ?";
   $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query, 'i', array($level));
   return $result;
}
```

Isso vai evitar que o erro aconteça novamente, e não esqueça de tratar o retorno das variáveis.
Ex.:

```
if(empty($username)){
   return "Username não pode ser vazio"
}
```

Comment: o estranho é que a getMemberByUsername nao apresente problemas, e outras funções que estão no mesmo arquivo tbm nao,  e mesmo nao tendo variaveis declaradas anteriormente, somente dentro da função mesmo, e está solução que vc sugeriu eu ja havia tentado, vou fazer novamente mas de outra forma. Mas se tivér mais alguma sugestao pode mandar.

Comment: Eu não sei como está seu código, mas eu imagino que a variável $level não esteja chegando até a função.

Comment: ops, chegou sim, mas chegou vazia, como faço pra ela chegar com algum valor assim como as demais? o select nao é pra isso ?, no caso do username ele busca nos campos preenchidos pelo usuario, com base no login e senha tem que me trazer tbm no nivel de acesso do usuario ($level)

Comment: É porque não dá pra saber ao certo como você está fazendo os envios dos dados, na sua dúvida você posta apenas a demonstração das funções, essa solução que eu postei é pra nunca dar erro. Preciso de mais dados para poder te ajudar.

Comment: Na vdd esse código funciona perfeitamente, o que eu preciso é uma tela de login que armazena a opção do usuario sempre se manter logado. O que eu preciso é por condições de niveis de acesso, no caso usuario ou admin, entao criei a function para buscar (atraves do select) o nivel de acesso do cara que está tentando acessar. e na index há um bloco if onde eu coloquei a condição que deveria estar na variavel $level, se 1 é admin se 2 usuario. Vou tentar por o código aqui pra ver se vc consegue me ajudar, estou preso nisso desde ontem.

Comment: Ok, no aguardo.

Comment: tentei postar os prints, mas bloquearam affff

Comment: acho que consegui resolver jovem, mais testes serão necessarios ...

Answer (score -1):

runQuery($query, 's', array($username));
        return $result;
    }

    function getTokenByUsername($username,$expired) {
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "Select * from tbl_token_auth where username = ? and is_expired = ?";
        $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query, 'si', array($username, $expired));
        return $result;
    }

    function markAsExpired($tokenId) {
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "UPDATE tbl_token_auth SET is_expired = ? WHERE id = ?";
        $expired = 1;
        $result = $db_handle->update($query, 'ii', array($expired, $tokenId));
        return $result;
    }

    function insertToken($username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date) {
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_token_auth (username, password_hash, selector_hash, expiry_date) values (?, ?, ?,?)";
        $result = $db_handle->insert($query, 'ssss', array($username, $random_password_hash, $random_selector_hash, $expiry_date));
        return $result;
    }

    function getMemberNivel($level='2') {
        $db_handle = new DBController();
        $query = "Select * from members where nivel = ?";
        $result = $db_handle->runQuery($query, 'i', array($level));
        return $result;
    }

    function update($query) {
        mysqli_query($this->conn,$query);
    }
}
?>